# Можно ли получить такую разметку используя только Releative?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли получить такую разметку используя только Releative?
Без LinearLayout?

Так как в CSS такое реально. Там Releative имеет weight, вот хотел узнать такое в Android studio есть?

Comment: я думаю, что можно

Comment: тоже думаю, что вполне реально. FrameLayout очень хорошо сюда подойдет, imho

Comment: Просто я не знаю как в Releative сделать так чтобы объекты расположились сами как в linearLayout используя wieght. У Releative Weight нет. Оттуда и все пробелмы

Comment: МОЖЕТ вы код в ответ скинете все же

Comment: А как вообще из текста вашего вопросаможно угадать, что вам нужно так же использовать weight?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса немного непонятно, как же именно вы хотите размещать блоки друг относительно друга. Опишите закономерность точно словами. По картинке правда непонятно.

Comment: @saturov, суть такая что  размеры не известны, тобишь в LinearLayout есть weight и там по 50% указать можно и тем самым реить проблему, вот хотел узнать, а можно ли в Releative использовать такое же?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<ImageView
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Сорри я картинку не так нарисовать, можете глянуть теперь. Можете переделать ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Не так давно *Google* представила библиотеку поддержки `support:percent`, в которую входит компоновщик [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) - виджет позволяет указать размеры вложенных элементов в процентах от общего размера контейнера.

Со своей стороны предлагаю то же самое, что и в ответе [Shwarz Andrei](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489960/177345), только без избыточных атрибутов (похоже здесь постарался графический дизайнер AS, которому доверять такое ответственное дело никак не стоит) и с использованием `PercentRelativeLayout`.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_marginBottomPercent="35%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="10%"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Библиотека должна быть импортирована в проект

Comment: Я смотрю вы указываете статичные размеры, а в случае если не известны размеры, лишь известно что высота левых картинок по 50%. то как тогда быть? Просто я часто в Releative добавляю LinearLayout из за отсутсвия атрибутов weight, но часто тут при создании тем слышал что это не правильно и выглядит не проффесионально, вот и хотел узнать реально ли осущетсвить такое без LinearLayout?

Comment: @xTIGRx Кто вам сказал, что использование весов элементов - непрофессионально? Возможно это относилось именно к тому способу, которым их использовали именно вы, НО! в разметке это вполне полноправный атрибут и имеет все основания использоваться там, где в нем есть необходимость.